# Add object to an NSMutableArray from another view

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a dictionary with three objects, and I want to add this dictionary to an NSMutableArray in a previous view of the stack. This array is correctly synthesized in the mainviewcontroller. However when I try to

`[mainVC.fotoObjectArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fotoObject]];` Nothing gets added to the array.

It seems like I didnt alloc/init it correctly, but it's retained in a property in the previous view controller.

A user takes a picture, or selects from the album with a button. When he returns:

PhotoViewController.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
MainViewController *mainVC = (MainViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
[mainVC setFotoGenomen:@"Ja"];

i = @"foto";
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
[fotoObject setObject:[NSData dataWithData:imageData] forKey:@"image"];

[mainVC.fotoObjectArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fotoObject]];

//display image
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 120.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView setImage:image];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[imageView release];

}
```

At the same time the GPS gets logged at PhotoViewController.m when the view gets loaded

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = newLocation.coordinate; 

fotoObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[fotoObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
[fotoObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];

}
```

The 'fotoObject' dict contains the right keys and values. Now it just needs to put that dictionary in the NSMutableArray of MainViewController.m.

Comment: Check in the debugger that mainVC is actually the object you think it is - if you log mainVC.fotoObjectArray do you see anything? Are there any other objects in there?

Comment: Nope, when I log that, it returns null

Comment: mainVC, or mainVC.fotoObjectArray?

Comment: mainVC.fotoObjectArray returns null right after inserting the dictionary, and also returns null back in the mainviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you never initialise the array in mainVC. If you've just got synthesised accessors then they will return `nil` unless you have explicitly set up the array.

In mainVC's `viewDidLoad` method you could have something like:

```
if (!self.fotoObjectArray)
    self.fotoObjectArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This will ensure that you actually have an array to add things to.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I knew it was something like this.